# Getting an Error Using Dash for Figure as Invalid argument `figure.layout` passed into Graph, Expected `object`. Was supplied type `array`

Tags: python, pandas, plotly, plotly-dash

I am trying a code to plot some data using dash and I am thinking, I am doing it right. But not sure why getting a very peculiar message ( plotly 3.8.1 and dash 0.42)

The error message I am getting is :

```
Invalid argument figure.layout passed into Graph with ID “graph-with-slider”. Expected object. Was supplied type array.
```

I have created an output which is working fine and giving data and the problem is in the layout and figure call. whicj I am not understanding.

```
 external_stylesheets = ['https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css']
#
app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets = external_stylesheets)
server = app.server

app.config['suppress_callback_exceptions'] = True
app.css.config.serve_locally = True
app.scripts.config.serve_locally = True

#
app.layout = html.Div([
        html.Div([
            html.H1('Testing Phase', style = {'text-align': 'center'}),


                html.H5('Enter ID'),
                dcc.Dropdown(
                    id = 'id',
                    style = {'width': '250px'},
                    options = [
                        {'label': 'AA', 'value': 'AA'},
                        {'label': 'AC', 'value': 'AC'},
                        {'label': 'UQ', 'value': 'UQ'},
                        {'label': 'NT', 'value': 'NT'},
                        {'label': 'PQ', 'value': 'PQ'}],
                    value = 'AA'
                ),

                html.H5('Enter Zone Yield Item'),
                dcc.Dropdown(
                    id = 'mz',
                    style = {'width': '200px'},
                    options = [
                        {'label': 'E1', 'value': 'E1'},
                        {'label': 'E2', 'value': 'E2'},
                        {'label': 'E3', 'value': 'E3'},
                        {'label': 'E4', 'value': 'E4'},
                        {'label': 'E5', 'value': 'E5'},
                        {'label': 'E6', 'value': 'E6'}],
                    value = 'E1'
                ),
    

                html.Br(),
                html.Br(),

                html.Button(
                    id = 'submit',
                    n_clicks = 0,
                    children = 'Submit'

                ),

                html.Br(),
                html.Br(),

                   html.Div([

                    dcc.Graph(
                        id='mygraph'
                    ),

                ]),

                html.Br(),
                html.Br(),

            ])
        ])

    ])

@app.callback(Output('mygraph', 'figure'),
                       [Input('submit', 'n_clicks')],
                       [State('pid', 'value'), State('mz', 'value')])])
def update_figure(n_clicks, pid, zone):

        mydf = SomeFuncFunc(id, zone)

        fit_data = mydf[0]

        l_col = fit_data.columns[2]

        z_col = fit_data.columns[3]  

        z2_col = fit_data.columns[4]

        l1_v = str(l_col)
        z1_v = str(z_col)


        print("Starting Trace")

        fits = []

        fits.append(go.Scatter(
            x = fit_data[l_col],
            y = fit_data[z_col],
            mode = 'markers',
            opacity = 0.9,
            marker = {
                'size': 20, 'symbol': "hexagon", "color": "orange",
                'line': {'width': 0.5, 'color': 'white'}
            },
            name = z1_v + "_" + "Plot",
        )),

        fits.append(go.Scatter(
             x = fit_data[l_col],
             y = fit_data[z2_col],
            mode = 'markers',
            opacity = 0.9,
            marker = {
                'size': 20, 'symbol': "diamond-open-dot", "color": "blue",
                'line': {'width': 0.9, 'color': 'red'}
            },
            name = z1_v + "_" + "Fit",
        )),

        mylayout = go.Layout(
             width = 800,
             height = 500,
            xaxis = {'title': 'X axis'},
            yaxis = {'title': 'Y axis'}
            margin={'l': 40, 'b': 40, 't': 10, 'r': 10},
            legend = {'x': 0, 'y': 1},
            hovermode = 'closest'
        ),
        fig = {'data':  fits, 'layout':mylayout}

        return fig



 if __name__ == '__main__':

      app.run_server(debug = True, port=8053)  #
```

It should plot the data. If I do not include layout, it is plotting, but not always.

The Error Details:

```
(This error originated from the built-in JavaScript code that runs Dash apps. Click to see the full stack trace or open your browser's console.)Error: Invalid argument `figure.layout` passed into Graph with ID "graphid".
Expected `object`.
Was supplied type `array`.
   at propTypeErrorHandler (http://127.0.0.1:8053/_dash-component-suites/dash_renderer/dash_renderer.dev.js?v=0.23.0&m=1557158783:40947:5)

   at CheckedComponent (http://127.0.0.1:8053/_dash-component-suites/dash_renderer/dash_renderer.dev.js?v=0.23.0&m=1557158783:37306:9)

   at Td (http://127.0.0.1:8053/_dash-component-suites/dash_renderer/react-dom@16.8.6.min.js?v=0.23.0&m=1557158783:82:9)

   at be (http://127.0.0.1:8053/_dash-component-suites/dash_renderer/react-dom@16.8.6.min.js?v=0.23.0&m=1557158783:91:477)

   at hi (http://127.0.0.1:8053/_dash-component-suites/dash_renderer/react-dom@16.8.6.min.js?v=0.23.0&m=1557158783:104:140)

   at Qg (http://127.0.0.1:8053/_dash-component-suites/dash_renderer/react-dom@16.8.6.min.js?v=0.23.0&m=1557158783:144:287)

   at Rg (http://127.0.0.1:8053/_dash-component-suites/dash_renderer/react-dom@16.8.6.min.js?v=0.23.0&m=1557158783:145:166)

   at Sc (http://127.0.0.1:8053/_dash-component-suites/dash_renderer/react-dom@16.8.6.min.js?v=0.23.0&m=1557158783:158:109)

   at Z (http://127.0.0.1:8053/_dash-component-suites/dash_renderer/react-dom@16.8.6.min.js?v=0.23.0&m=1557158783:156:492)

   at Kc (http://127.0.0.1:8053/_dash-component-suites/dash_renderer/react-dom@16.8.6.min.js?v=0.23.0&m=1557158783:155:69)
```

Comment: You're asking for debugging help, but it is going to be difficult for someone to reproduce your error without all of the code necessary to run the app. However, it is unlikely someone would jump into debugging something that complex for you. I would suggest you take the following steps:
1. Copy the full stack trace for the "Invalid argument..." error you mentioned to a new file.
2. Carefully examine the stack trace to find where *your code* passes a value into a *library's code*.
3. Insert a print statement to see what value you're passing to the library.
4. Re-read the library's API docs.

Comment: Thanks. I tried to paste the error:

Comment: In the last section of the original post

Comment: I think I can help, but it's not easy without a sample dataframe. First, remove this line `app.config['suppress_callback_exceptions'] = True`. There are actual errors being suppressed that shouldn't be. Second, I think this line `dcc.Dropdown(id = 'id',` is supposed to have `id='pid'`, because you use `pid` in your `State` values. I think I'll need a sample dataframe to do much more. There are also some paren and bracket mismatches that I had to fix to get things running.

Comment: Thanks. Figured the problem is due to the comma at the end of layout, which triggered the graph layout to be taken as an array instead of object. It is working fine now.

Answer (score 4):

Figured the problem is due to the comma at the end of layout, which triggered the graph layout to be taken as an array instead of object. It is working fine now.